# Embed YouTube video with tracklist navigation

Tags: html, youtube, querystringparameter

I want to embed a YouTube video on my website that's a full-length music album and create a tracklist navigation so that the user can click to individual songs in the album.

I know the basic way to embed a YouTube iframe:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uRDgVEJKx5c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How would i create the navigation?

Answer (score 1):

First, use the standard YouTube iframe embed code, and then add a name attribute:

Example:

```
<iframe name="iframeYouTube" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uRDgVEJKx5c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Then create a nav on the same page with deep-links to specific times in the YouTube video. Use an anchor tag that targets the name of the iframe, and add a couple query string parameters to the YouTube embed URL:

- **start** set to number of seconds in video
- **autoplay** set to true

Example:

```
<a target="iframeYouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uRDgVEJKx5c?start=672&autoplay=1">Glorious Lion</a>
```

See [my CodePen example](http://codepen.io/asonnenshine/pen/pbQrVp)